# How to maintain login state of my app in android

Tags: android

How to maintain Login state of my application when

1. After killed via task manager
2. while switch off my device. How could i do this pro-grammatically in android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
getSharedPreferences("Name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true).commit();
```

when Logging in set this. After logout

```
getSharedPreferences("Name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false).commit();
```

Or if your server is returning a session after log-in you can save that session in `SharedPreferences` and use it for future API requests.

You can also rely on `onSavedInstanceState` function to save some values that will help you to recreate your views. That also will help.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(key, value);
}
```

[See the developer doc for more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: what if user "Clear Data" from Manage Applications?

Comment: That case you can ask the user to log-in again.

Comment: Nope.My question is im not suppose to login again.initially i may in 3 or 4 or 5th screen.But after killed,when app starts,i can able to know whether it is logged in or not.But how could i know my last screen i was in?

Comment: @Rajesh In which activity i need to use this code onSaveInstanceState..?

Comment: You can implement it in every Activities and while recreation you can create your views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the username and password in shared preferences encrypted.

Use those username, password and do a login once again in background (not foreground).

Comment: Nope.i shouldn't do login again.Ex.Initially i logged in & i was in 3rd screen after that.On that situation i killed tht app using Task manager.Again when im open my app.it should be in that 3rd screen.How could i do that?pls suggest

Comment: as Rajesh CP mentioned, store the login status in shared prferences and check that status on the first activity and then if its logged in then start 3rd activity and do finish for first activity.

Comment: ok thx.but im getting sessionId from server while login.if i follow your step,the sessionId will not stored.

Comment: Anyway the session will be expired after sometime after that u have to login again. I asked u to do the login in background not in foreground.